PreparedStatement still triggering VeraCode SQL-injection finding
The following implementation of a generic update-method triggers VeraCode SQL-injection finding on the pstmt.executeUpdate() call:
    public final int update(String sql, Object... args) {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        int row = 0;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            int column = 0;
            ResultSetMetaData md = pstmt.getMetaData();
            for (Object arg : args) {
                column++;
                pstmt.setObject(column, arg,
                    md.getColumnType(column));
            }
            row = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            handleException(e, sql, args);
        } finally {
            close(con, pstmt);
        }
        return row;
    }

...
        update("update foo set bar=1 where foo = ?", 11);

However, this seemingly similar alternative passes VeraCode analysis without a problem:
    public final int update(String sql, MyJdbcParamSetter paramSetter) {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        int row = 0;
        try {
            con = getConnection();
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            paramSetter.setParameters(pstmt);
            row = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            List<Object> args = paramSetter.getArguments();
            handleException(e, sql, args);
        } finally {
            close(con, pstmt);
        }
        return row;
    }

...
        dao.update("update foo set bar = 1 where foo = ?", new MyJdbcParamSetter
            @Override
            public void setParameters(PreparedStatement pstmt) throws SQLException {
                pstmt.setInteger(1, 11);
            }
        });

I understand, that the SQL-text could be troublesome -- and the static scanner does not know, where that text is coming from.
But that should be true about both methods. Yet, only the first one -- the one easier to use -- triggers VeraCode... Why is that?
